# How to use a custom built, authorized ASP.NET Core Web API in other Core web apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core

So I built a custom Web API in ASP.NET Core which is authorized by role. What would be the correct way to use this API in other Core web apps? How should I go about authorizing an application to use an API?

Edit: A little more detail on what I'm trying to do:

So let's say I have an authorization policy. In my separate Web API app, I declare that policy in Startup and authorize some API methods. It works, and is now hosted at "webapi.foo.com", awesome. Now let's say I create a new, separate web app and I want to use some method from that API. So I guess my question is two-fold: How do I call those methods at "webapi.foo.com"? And how do I ensure that my app has permission to call those authorized methods?

Comment: "How should I go about authorizing an application to use an API?" is a broad question. There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I replied to someone else with this. Hopefully this narrows it down a bit: So let's use your policy authorization example. In my separate Web API app, I declare that policy in Startup and authorize some API methods. It works, and is now hosted at "webapi.foo.com", awesome. Now let's say I create a new, separate web app and I want to use some method from that API. So I guess my question is two-fold: How do I call those methods at "webapi.foo.com"? And how do I ensure that my app has permission to call those authorized methods?

Comment: If you foresee development of many web apps that would need to communicate with each other in an authorized framework, you would benefit from developing a web app that just does authorization management for your other web apps, or in other words an Identity Provider. You could implement an Authorization Token or HMAC or any other mechanism that would provide you the same capability.

Comment: The question is still too broad. All anyone will be able to offer is general guidance. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Authorization**
I accomplished this using Json Web Tokens (JWTs) and Bearer Authentication by having the front end system (webapp.foo.com) call a login method on the backend API (api.foo.com).  The login method at api.foo.com authenticates the user and issues a JWT in it's response.  webapp.foo.com then uses this JWT to authenticate actions in it's controllers (by defining an authorization policy that uses the token's claims) and also passes the token to foo.api.com whenever it makes a call there.  Both webapp.foo.com and api.foo.com just need to build their authorization policies based on the JWT's claim set and then they can share the use of the token.

**Calling api.foo.com**

```
            string jwt = xxx.yyy.zzz; //use the actual JWT returned from your login call
        var client = new HttpClient("http://api.foo.com");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwt); //add the JWT to the authorization header
        var requestStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { myParam = viewModel.myParam }); //serialize the object you are passing as a parameter to api.foo.com as Json
        HttpContent requestBody = new StringContent(requestStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("myController\\myAction", requestBody);  //POST to api.foo.com (or whatever action you want to take)
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var resultstr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; //read the result as a string
        dynamic resultObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(resultstr); //if desired, deserialize it to an object (I just used dynamic as an example)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I understand your question correctly.

If you decorate the controller/actions with an AuthorizeAttribute that uses a named policy, then web apps that consume your controller library can define the named policy in startup and configure which roles or claims or other requirements to allow access.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "SystemLogPolicy")]
```

startup example:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        "SystemLogPolicy",
        authBuilder =>
        {
            authBuilder.RequireRole("ServerAdmins");
        });
}
```

see also the [docs on authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/index.html)

Comment: Hmm sorry I should have been more clear in the OP. So let's use your policy authorization example. In my separate Web API app, I declare that policy in Startup and authorize some API methods. It works, and is now hosted at "webapi.foo.com", awesome. Now let's say I create a new, separate web app and I want to use some method from that API. So I guess my question is two-fold: How do I call those methods at "webapi.foo.com"? And how do I ensure that my app has permission to call those authorized methods?

Comment: I think you should edit your question to make it more clear, seems like maybe you should look into jwt